# Reliably find the address of the current process' _write() function from a user mode win32 application

Tags: c++, windows

I'm working on writing an application that can capture stdout/stderr and debug messages from any user-mode process on the system and print it to its console. There have been several situations where I have been writing programs in the past and due to the nature of the program, be it a GUI, windows service, etc...; Console output cannot be seen simply because there is no console. The obvious fix for this is to change print statements to debug print statements like `OutputDebugString()` and then attach a debugger and see the output. Sometimes it can be tricky, especially in kernel mode debugging, to setup a debugger and see the output you want.

Ideally this application I'm writing will allow you to specify a PID (and eventually will handle drivers, don't worry about that now) - and without attaching to the application as a debugger, it will display all output destined for the debugger, stdout, or stderr.

To do this I have created an application that will inject a DLL into any process on the system. From the DLL I insert a trampoline hook into the `_write()` procedure to catch data destined for stdout and stderr from cout, cerr, wcout, wcerr, printf, and fprintf. My issue right now is that the address of the `_write()` procedure changes on each run of a target application. Currently I'm running the target application in windbg and doing `x program!_write` to find the address, hard-coding it and testing my hook.

**TLDR**

How does Windbg find the address of `_write()` when I run the `x program!_write` command? How can I do the same thing from a DLL injected into a target process without symbols?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Source code for my current progress can be found here: https://github.com/vix597/StJude

Also if there's a better way to redirect stdout/stderr from a target process with an injected DLL, I'm all ears. I have tried `freopen` but the only output that gets redirected is output originating from the injected DLL itself and not the application the DLL is injected into. I'm working under the assumption that I don't have control over the target applications source code. I also haven't verified that `_write()` gets called when there is no console.

**UPDATE**

Previous to asking this question my test program was compiled with MFC in a static library. When using standard windows libraries Windbg finds `_write()` in `MSVCR120`. This may have been cause for some confusion for those attempting to answer the question so to be more clear:

How can I find the address of the `_write()` method regardless of the way the C++ runtimes in the target application were compiled and regardless of what version of the C++ runtime environment is being used?

I essentially want something like this:

```
LPVOID fnWrite = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"<module_name>"),"_write");
```

However, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

About your question on how Windbg does it, it uses the debug API of Windows. With it you have ways to insert breakpoints, etc. Specifically, to have the address of a function in the program you use the [dbghelp DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679291(v=vs.85).aspx) (you need to have the PDB for this to work).

But for the use you have there's an easier solution, provided the application uses the runtime as a DLL: to put a hook on that entry point. Take a look at [This page in CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730/APIHijack-A-Library-for-easy-DLL-function-hooking).

Comment: Thanks, but what if the target application was compiled with MFC in a static library? This looks like it would only work if the `_write()` function was in a DLL external to the target application.

Comment: You're right. If it was compiled with the static RTL, you'd need to discover the address using dbghelp, place a breakpoint on it, and do your logic when the breakpoint is hit. That'd work only if you had the PDB for the application. Unfortunately, what you want to accomplish has no solution without drawbacks, and certainly no solution that'd work  always. An executable compiled with other toolchain couldn't be used in both cases, also.

Comment: What you could do, however, is to get to a lower level: _write internally calls WriteFile, which resides in kernel32.dll. So if you hook WriteFile instead, it'd always work, no matter how the RTL was linked, which compiler generated the exe, and if you have the PDB or not.

Comment: Eventually, you may want to hook `WriteConsole` etc., as well.

Comment: Well noted @HarryJohnston.